# Handling anchor tag click using marionette

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, backbone.js, marionette

What i want is to handle the anchor button click inside my **Marionette.ItemView events**. I **don't want to use href** in anchor tag. I want to handle the click in my itemview and ask the **backbone approuter** to change page.

I want to switch my page from **index** to **myaccount** on an anchor button click. My template looks like below

```
<div>
    <a data-role="button" id="btn_eclipse" class="btn_eclipse_myaccount"><%= val_btn_myaccount %></a>
    <a data-role="button" id="btn_eclipse" class="btn_eclipse_services"><%= val_btn_services %></a>
    <a data-role="button" id="btn_eclipse" class="btn_eclipse_offers"><%= val_btn_offers %></a>
</div>
```

My Marionette.ItemView capture events like this

```
events : {
    'click input[type="button"]' : 'onButtonClick',
    'blur input[type="text"]' : 'onKeyPress',
    'click a' : 'onAnchorButtonClick',
},          
onAnchorButtonClick : function(obj){
    obj.preventDefault;
    var btn_id = $(obj.target).attr('id');
    console.log("The button clicked id is==="+$(obj.target).attr('id'));
    //here i trigger event to change page
}
```

I am not able to retrieve that ID or any other attribute like **href** as you specified in your answer from the anchor tag.

Please advice what should i do.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4):

You can do what you want with something like this:

```
var MyView = Backbone.Marionette.ItemView.extend({
  events : {
    "click a" : "handleRouting"
  },

  handleRouting : function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    Backbone.history.navigate(/*whatever your route is*/, true);
  }
});
```

While the above will work, what I would instead recommend is doing what you don't want to do, namely use the `href` on the `a` tag and have a global listener that hooks into the routing.

Per your comment question, you can implement a global listener with something like the following:

```
$(document).on("click", "a", function (e) {
  var href = $(this).attr("href");
  if (href && href.match(/^\/.*/) && $(this).attr("target") !== "_blank") {
    e.preventDefault();
    Backbone.history.navigate(href, true);
  }
});
```

If you are using the HTML push API (rather than #!s) then something like the above will capture link clicks that route them through your `Backbone.Router`.

Comment: Hello Andrew, Thanks for the reply..Can you please tell me how to implement the second href option with global listener. @Andrew

Comment: I updated my answer to give an example that would work for using `hrefs` and regular tags to hook into the bb router. Let me know if this doesn't work for you or if you have other questions.

Comment: Hello @Andrew. Thanks for the answer. But can you please help me to retrieve href attribute within my Marionette.ItemView. I have updated my code above, I am unable to retrieve href or id or an other attribute from my anchor tag. Please help.

Comment: Your code looks close to correct. It is possible that you should be using `event.currentTarget` instead of `event.target` if you have markup inside the `a` tag that you are actually clicking. Also, it might be a typo, but you need to actually call `event.preventDefault();`.

Answer (score 0):

I have implemented a `behavior` to take care of this automatically using the `v-href` attribute

https://github.com/samccone/marionette-behaviors#viewlinks

I use this extensively in all of my apps, and it works like a charm!

Comment: unfortunately this isn't really an answer, but your repo made for interesting browsing nonetheless...